# integer vs integers

Tags: phrases, grammatical-number

What a wonderful community this is!

My question relates to the below question I translated from a non-English Maths question for high school Maths. Did I word the question correctly? I'm not sure if I have as there are multiple possible values for the integer x. Should have I have "satisfies" or "satisfy"?

Another phrase I'm not sure about is "...find the value of a and b". Is this correct? Can I also use "...find the values of a and b"?

[image]

Thanks guys.

Comment: As you've used the plural "integers" and they are the subject, "satisfy" is the correct verb which agrees with it. As for "find the value of..." if you're finding the values of multiple things I'd use the plural just to avoid any ambiguity. Some people (admittedly not many as it's a bit of a stretch) would parse "Find the value of a and b" to mean the result of adding them together, which obviously isn't what you want.

Comment: And what would you have them do if they were to discover that there are only 13 such integers? Basically don't use "find the value-if", either use "what is the value-if" or say "There are 14 positive integers ..., find the value of n"

Comment: @Born2Smile I can see what you mean, but there is an intent in such questions being posed in this conventional form.  As it happens, there really is a unique solution to this equation, but part of the point is not to tell students even that much.  The point of the exercise is not so much extracting the right answer (which could be achieved by guesswork or voting, say), as getting students to show the reasoning and understanding in reaching it.  ‘If’ is there partly to allow for the possibility of 'there are 14 positive integers x' being false.

Comment: @Born2Smile The modification of phrasing that I would suggest, however, would be to specify =exactly= 14 integers x.  The thing is, there is one single value for that.  Purely by inspection, with the question in its current form a student might correctly state that there is a countably infinite (I think...) number of answers that provide 14 (and some more) such integers!

Comment: @CaptainCranium "Is there a positive integer *n* such that there are exactly 14 integers *x* that satify [...], and if so, what is the value of *n*" or similar

Comment: We're throwing the *proofreading* VtC reason out the window for this question but I find this interesting, so ... "Find the positive integer n for which exactly 14 positive integers x satisfy n < \sqrt{x} < n+1".

Comment: @Lawrence  I don't think a VtC is appropriate, mainly because of the second part of the question, which is markedly less emphatic but more linguistically interesting (as my answer has tried to show).

Comment: @CaptainCranium I didn't vote to close, but this question does (at best) sail close to the wind. Be glad that no one has down-voted your answer because they felt the question was off-topic or similar (with the goal of keeping standards high). This is not my position on the matter, just fair warning.

Comment: @Born2Smile...  In natural language your formulation and Lawrence's are both fine. Maths questions, however, use a very chopped form that is basically philosophy. 'If' introduces an assumption (in this case concerning _x_ and its relationship to _n_), and the question asks you to follow-through the consequences of that assumption _if it is correct_. Sometimes one discovers that it is provably wrong. In both philosophy and maths, this is often used in the process of a _reductio ad absurdum_. It is a very specialised but sound formulation, which I take to be the essential point of the example..

Comment: @Lawrence I appreciate that, and I realise (sorry I wasn't clear) that you didn't VtC.  In exactly the same high-standards spirit, I am trying to protect a question that will seem either inaccessible or irrelevant to some, but which I believe legitimately addresses usage in a specialised context.  If it were economics or poetry, it would be safer.

Comment: @Lawrence Oh, and... OP didn't highlight the detail of this, but it is also partly an issue of technical translation into English, in what looks like an academic context requiring some kind of conventional usage standard.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This is a delightful little question, though I think my enjoyment came from the maths rather than the English. There are 3 votes to close the question. In an effort to avoid closure (or in a bid to reopen it if it does get closed), try editing your question to (1) highlight the *value vs values* part which *may* be debatable in the 'dialect' of English used in maths, (2) improve your grammar (e.g. *question below*, not *below question*), and (3) extract the essential portion of the (single) question you're asking, and ask *that*.

Comment: @CaptainCranium No problem. I wonder whether it's arguable that the style of English used in maths is as valid a style of English as is AmE and BrE. On the *if X find Y* vs *find Y such that X* formulations, the former is perhaps more common but both are valid in a maths-related academic context - it's about intent and clarity. Here's an example of the [second form](https://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Trigonometry-basics/Trigonometry-basics.faq.question.287526.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically, your first usage is correct, but the second introduces a more complex issue and in most contexts will work better as a plural.

The thing about integers…  Yes, this is simple:  *14 separate integers* (and thanks to barmy curiosity and nostalgia for maths, I now know what they are!) *satisfy* this equation.  This is similar to saying that *14 species of starfish* or *14 British monarchs* (clear plural) *demonstrate* specified characteristics.  The grammar is simple.

The second example is not so absolute, although there is subtlety here that is more to do with the intent and environment of the question than with grammar *per se*.

Requesting a *single* ‘value’ will probably be helpful only if you have already stated that (perhaps under certain conditions) ***a*** and ***b*** must be equal.  If your question relates specifically to that kind of case, then at some given instant (or many different ones, in fact) ***a*** and ***b*** might share *the same single value* (which might vary depending on other things!).  Underneath it all, this kind of question is not centrally about ***a*** and ***b*** at all:  it is really about identifying *that single value* as ***a*** and ***b*** shift.

For example, at any given moment a warehouse might contain ***a*** (a numerical quantity of) widgets that are sold at price ***b*** according to some sliding scale.  Your question might suggest that at a certain point the stock level numerically equals the trading price, in which case it could make sense to ask for *the single numerical value* of ***a***-and-***b***.

This might be the odd sort of question whose actual point is to help students realise that equality occurs for the real-world-perplexing but mathematically meaningful moment when (for example) we have π (3.14159...) widgets on the shelves. This is then the *single value* of ***a*** and ***b*** at which such a condition is definitely true, even if it can never be empirically observed.  As I am trying to demonstrate, this happens when the question is essentially about how one might identify the *single value* in a mathematical relationship, not really about the properties (quantity and price, in this case) themselves.

More likely, however, ***a*** and ***b*** have distinct *values*—which conceivably might at times (possibly at all times, following a bit of analysis) be identical, but which are nominally independent at first glance and/or for practical purposes.

An example of this might involve measurements of a body’s mass (***a***), and the acceleration of some other body towards it (***b***).  Under some arbitrary system of units, those measurements simply will always be identical because the quantities concerned are directly proportional.  The actual values ***a*** and ***b*** (mass and acceleration), however, would typically be dealt with independently and would normally be described as having distinct (plural) *values*, even if (using a particular system of units) they will always be numerically identical.

Here, then, it would be more conventional to describe ***a*** and ***b*** as having (plural) *values*, whether or not those values might sometimes be equal.

[I might well come back and edit this, especially in light of anything non-mathematicians have to say about it.  I expect OP can see what I generally mean, but I am striving to get across something to do with domain-based usage rather than grammar as such, and it might not be as clear as I have been hoping.]

Answer (score 3):

Following the plural "integers" you are correct to use "**satisfy**".

If you had been looking for a single "integer" then "satisfies" would be correct.